# Solving inverse of function

Tags: inverse, exponential-function

Given:

$f(t)=500(1.1)^t$

How would I mathmatically solve for:

$f^{-1}(3000)$

Comment: Solve $3000=500(1.1)^t$. First divide both sides by $500$, then take logs...

Comment: @DavidMitra That would be for $f(t)$, not $f^{-1}(t)$.

Comment: No @DavidMitra is right .

Comment: @Jossie $f^{-1}(3000)$ is the value $t$ for which $f(t)=3000$.

Comment: @Jossie $ f(t) = 500(1.1)^t \Rightarrow f^{-1} ( 500(1.1)^t ) = t $

Comment: Doh, I forgot to divide out the 500 before trying to use $ln$ no wonder I was hitting a brick wall.

Comment: @BobDunakey Yeah, see below for the details.

Comment: You could have smashed that wall by writing $\ln\bigl(500(1.1)^t\bigr)=\ln 500+\ln (1.1)^t$ and proceed from there. Dividing through by $500$ first, of course, makes things slightly easier.

Comment: @DavidMitra that's essentially my answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easier suggestion:
\begin{align*}
&3000=500(1.1)^{t} \Longrightarrow\\
&6 = (1.1)^{t} \Longrightarrow\\
&\ln{6} = t \ln{1.1} \Longrightarrow\\
&t = \frac{\ln{6}}{\ln{1.1}}\Longrightarrow\\
\end{align*}
So if we have the coordinate pair $\left(\frac{\ln{6}}{\ln{1.1}}, 3000 \right) \in f$,  then
$\left(3000,\frac{\ln{6}}{\ln{1.1}}\right)\in f^{-1}$ 
Yielding $$f^{-1}(3000) = \frac{\ln{6}}{\ln{1.1}}$$

Answer (score 0):

1) Reverse $f(t)$ and $t$

$t = 500(1.1)^{f(t)}$

2) Solve for $f(t)$ (which is really now $f^{-1}(t)$)

Hint: use logarithms

3) Plug in $f^{-1}(3000)$.